# The dual basis properties

Tags: linear-algebra

So my professor gave this question which I do not understand where is my mistake.

Let us look at the standard basis for $R^{3}$.

and let $p_{1},p_{3},p_{3}$ be the dual basis of the standard basis.

Therefore after short calculation in the draft I saw that:

$p_{1}=(1,0,0)$

$p_{2}=(0,1,0)$

$p_{3}=(0,0,1)$

Let us look at the next basis for $R^{3}$

$v_{1}= \begin{pmatrix}\ 1\\\ 0\\\ 0\\\end{pmatrix}$
$v_{2}= \begin{pmatrix}\ 1\\\ 1\\\ 0\\\end{pmatrix}$
$v_{3}= \begin{pmatrix}\ 2\\\ 3\\\ 1\\\end{pmatrix}$

and let $q_{1},q_{3},q_{3}$ be the dual basis of this basis.

My professor ask me to express each $q_{i}$ using $p_{1},p_{3},p_{3}$

And the answer is:

$q_{1} = p_{1}-p_{2}+2p_{3}$

$q_{2} = p_{2}-3p_{3}$

$q_{3} = p_{3}$

But as far as I for each $i$ $q_{i}(v_{i})=1$ and for $j\neq i$ $q_{i}(v_{j})=0$

Therefore after short calculation in the draft I saw that:

$q_{1}=(1,0,0)$

$q_{2}=(0,1,0)$

$q_{3}=(0,0,1)$

meaning $q_{i}=p_{i}$

So where is my mistake ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Putting basis aside (it is generally better not to use basises anyway), we have two spaces here: $V=\mathbb R^3$ and its dual $V^*$. Whatever basis $v_1,v_2,v_3$ of $V$ you select, the corresponding diual basis is *always* given by $q_i(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$. However, we are given $v_i$ in terms of (the only basis of $\mathbb R^3$ that we can unambiguously communicate about, namely) the standard basis. And we want to unambiguously describe the dual basis vectors $q_i$ as elements of $V^*$, that is as linear maps $q_i\colon V\to \mathbb R$, that is: by specifying the function value $q_i(x,y,z)$ at an arbitrary point $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$. So it is not useful to merely "state the obvious" that e.g. $q_3(2,3,1)=1$ and $q_3(1,1,0)=q_3(1,0,0)=0$.

Comment: ok, I understood. I should look at the $q_{i}$ as the linearmap regardless to which basis I want to represent it's matrix and from there it is easy to see. Thanks !!